# Каким членом предложения является словосочетание «все равно»?

Tags: члены-предложения

Каким членом предложения является словосочетание «все равно» в предложении «Ему все равно»?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В безличном предложении «Ему все равно» это сказуемое.